# Use lua to do something in MUD room

Tags: lua

This is my first time using an embedded language like this.

I'm trying to learn using lua as a script inside of MUSHclint, a sort of text-based role playing client.

In the client, if you just type the word **help** and hit enter, then it displays a help screen.  If you type in **"help** then you get *Character says, "Help"*

In lua, I've made:

```
function hello ()
    print("\"hello")
end
```

What I get is a *"hello* from the lua interpreter.  Is there a way to make it "hello as if I typed it directly?

The end goal here is to create a random response when a person "CharacterX wants item"  I know I'm way over my head, but please be nice to me.

Comment: my apologies The slash is going the wrong way

    function hello ()
        print("\"hello")
    end

Comment: @BradBailey: Edit your post and put that into it. Also, doesn't the MUSHclint have some documentation you could look through, an API for sending messages to it?

Answer (score 3):

In MUSH, you'd just do:

```
Send('"hello')
```

At least, that's if you're using the "Send to Script" option (rather than "Send to World"). MUSHClient has forums that are probably better suited to ask your questions regarding their product, though.

Comment: You don't need to escape the double quote inside single quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I forgot that!